# Romper el encapsulamiento en C#

Tags: c#, poo, encapsulamiento, propiedades

Declarar los atributos de una clase de la forma

```
class Cliente
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

No sería romper el encapsulamiento? Es decir, no tendría que tener un `getId()` y `setId()`, por ejemplo, por cada atributo que tenga? Es buena practica declarar de esta forma las clases en C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dices las **propiedades** deben devolver el valor de un **atributo privado** de la clase o bien darle un valor a este **atributo privado**.

```
class Cliente
{
   private string nombre;

   public GetNombre()
   {
      return nombre;
   }

   public SetNombre(string value)
   {
      nombre = value;
   }
}
```

Aquí lo hacemos a través de **métodos** **get** y **set** como tú dices, pero existe un tipo de método especial conocido como **propiedades** las cuales en un solo método juntan los **get** y los **set**.

```
class Cliente
{
   private string nombre;

   public string Nombre
   {
      get {return nombre;}
      set {nombre = value;}
   }
}
```

Como ves aquí se utiliza una **propiedad** para acceder a los **atributos privados** de la clase.

Pero que pasaría si tu clase tuviera **10** propiedades, el código sería demasiado largo ya que tendrías que declarar **10** atributos privados con sus respectivas propiedades o métodos individuales **get** y **set**, lo que sería demasiado código para cualquiera de los ejemplos de arriba.

Aquí es cuando se hace uso un recurso del lenguaje conocido como **sugar syntax** o **azúcar sintáctico**, que en esencia es escribir menos código, usando **sugar syntax** tu código quedaría así

```
class Cliente
{
   public string Nombre {get; set;}
}
```

Aquí declaramos la **propiedad** e internamente el compilador se encarga de administrar los **atributos privados**, ya no tenemos que escribirlo nosotros, lo cual aumenta nuestra productividad.

Para crear propiedades dentro de nuestra clase de una manera rápida usando atajos del teclado puedes poner la palabra **prop** y apretar dos veces consecutivas la **tecla** **Tab** y en nuestro editor de código se pondrá una plantilla de la propiedad, lo único que tendrás que hacer es poner el tipo de dato y el nombre de la propiedad.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me aclaraste la duda y encima me aprendí ese atajo!